# Audible Authorization Issues Since iTunes 10.4

Tags: macos, itunes

I'm having a couple of issues with my Audible Audiobooks after my upgrade to Lion and iTunes 10.4.

1. Audible is permanently "authorized", even though it's not. When choosing the "Deauthorize Audible Account" menu option, I log into Audible, then I authenticate using my local/computer credentials, and a dialog pops up stating my account has been Deauthorized. Returning to the Advanced menu continues to show 'Deauthorize', in which I can continue this process over, and over, and over.
2. When sync'ing my iOS device, I always get a dialog talking about my computer being unauthorized from allowing the audiobooks to sync.

There are no settings on audible.com regarding this authorization, so iTunes is the only frontend I can use to manage this, but clearly I'm stuck somewhere. How can I overcome this issue in order to listen to my audiobooks again?

Comment: Related: I found Audible emails one-time passwords if you try to authenticate with an older version of iTunes, such as 10.x (which you may be using if, say, your only CD burner is on a PowerPC Mac).

Answer (score 1):

1. Quit iTunes on every computer you own *(probably not necessary but can't hurt).*
2. Contact Audible.com support and ask them to de-authorize every device associated with your account.
3. Go back into iTunes and re-authorize.

I've been an Audible customer for years and they have some of the best customer support in the entire tech industry. You can contact them via [Email](http://www.audible.com/email-help) or phone:

- 1-888-283-5051 (US & Canada)
- 1-973-820-0400 (International)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues you described, and if I remember correctly, I fixed this by unchecking Audiobooks when syncing my iPhone, and then re-enabled it + synced again.

Comment: I've unchecked `Sync Audiobooks` on both my iPhone and iPad and sync'ed each. Went through the deauthorize process again... nope. The menu still says "Deauthorize Audible Account" and continues to say "Deauthorized" after all the authentication steps.

Comment: My menu also says "Deauthorize Audible Account" (which is correct, if account is properly authorized). I'm pretty sure that's all what I did to get rid of iTunes warnings. Maybe contact Audible support, they were very responsive last time I need to contact them.